# Broken accent characters when Copy / Paste into ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding

I am copy pasting from an MS word document into an ASCX file.  When I view the ascx file, the accented characters appear normally.  BUT, when the page is rendered through my ASP.net application, the accented characters are broken:

`Une promenade  dans un verger ensoleillÃ©, un peau de pÃªche dÃ©licatement parfumÃ©eâ€¦ Les  plaisirs du printemps vous attendent!`

The page is specifying UTF-8 encoding which I believe is required to show them correctly.

`<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />`

Normally, this works fine and the accented characters appear normally (other pages I have created on the same site still show correctly).  BUT, now I can't seem to get this to work right.  So previously, I have no issues with this, but now I cannot see what I have done different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ascx file was loaded into another ascx which was ANSI encoded.  When I both were encoded UTF-8, the characters displayed normally.

Answer (score 0):

did you copy directly into the html view? --- if you copy it on the designer it is probably encoding the characters.

I am not sure why they weren't encoded for this page, but make sure to encode all of them in the aspx html view, like `&aacute;` for the á, or `&oacute;` for the ó

Comment: Pasting in either code view or design view works fine, its only after these characters go through my application. The same application that displays the same characters on other pages normally.